# Authentication in Web Application Toolkit for FAQs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I'm modifying this for a website: 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/toolkitfaqs

The current authentication was using forms to secure the faqs/admin directory, I want to use windows authentication.

I have two webconfigs, 1 at the root level and one inside the faqs/admin directory.

Root Level config has this:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
</system.web>
<location path="Faq/Admin">
      <system.web>
           <authorization>
                <allow roles="Domain\group1, Domain\group2" />
            <deny users="*" />
            <deny users="?"/>
       </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The web config inside the faqs/admin directory has this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="true"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I try to hit the faqs/admin directory I receive this error:

> Access is denied.  Description: An
>   error occurred while accessing the
>   resources required to serve this
>   request. The server may not be
>   configured for access to the requested
>   URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized:
>   Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.  Verify that you have
>   permission to view this directory or
>   page based on the credentials you
>   supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server. 
>   Contact the Web server's administrator
>   for additional assistance.

Does this work differently in mvc projects? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!